Reference for unknown notion related to continuity
I was studying general topology when a question came to my mind.
Let's consider a continuous function f between two topological spaces (for sake of conveniency, I'll indicate just their topologies) T (domain) and S (codomain). It is known, for example, that refining the topology on the domain or coarsening the one on the codomain preserves continuity.
Let's call f precise between the topologies T and S if, for every topologies T' coarser than T and S' finer than S and such that f is continuous from T' to S', it is true that T is coarser than T' and S is finer than S' (i.e. T = T' and S = S').
I have a sense that this property can be useful to characterise final and initial topologies induced by a map and a topology, including identifications. Anyone has ever seen anything like that in a treatise on topology, or some analogous, or has any observation in merit?
EDIT What is the appropriate setting to study the topologies that make a given function continuous? Is it a poset, or a lattice, or something more specific?

I think what you are saying is that $T$ is the initial topology of $f$ wrt to $S$, respectively $S$ is the final topology of $f$ wrt $T$.

And assuming $f$ surjective, because we have no idea what happens outside the range.

Given the few hints collected, maybe due to the vagueness of the question, I’ve made it a bit more specific.
